# Excel: Button action code - Why can't I use a Workbook And Sheet Module

Tags: vba, excel, button

I have a Personal Workmap with a template ( with vba code and a button action ) that I copy into a worksheet when needed. It creates a Table of sheet to quickly access many, > 25 sheets, like a fake popup ( excel 2016 macos ). It did works well when I did program it directly into the sheet module. It collects the sheets and creates buttons with the following code.

```
Set btnRng = TOC_WS.Range(Cells(lastRow, btnCol), Cells(lastRow, btnCol))
            Set btn = TOC_WS.Buttons.Add(btnRng.Left, btnRng.Top, btnRng.Width, btnRng.Height)
            With btn
                .OnAction = "btnAction"
                .Caption = WS.Name
                .Name = WS.Name
            End With
```

And the button sub....

```
Sub btnAction()
   ......
End Sub
```

But now for some reason it doesn't work when the called sub is in the Sheet-module. I get the notification that it can't be found. If I put it into a code Module the it works. I did of course search te web, but couldn't find anything that say's it can't working.

My question - How can I get the button action back working into the same sheet-module as the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General, when a routine is a member of a Worksheet, the worksheet's name is implicitly  part of the routine's name.

```
btn.OnAction = "Sheet1.btnAction"
```

Or, as in your code you want to bind it to a routine in the TOC_WS sheet:

```
btn.OnAction = TOC_WS.CodeName & ".btnAction"
```

Moreover, if you want to move the routine to the code module `ThisWorkbook`,

```
btn.OnAction = "ThisWorkbook.btnAction"
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, but I still got the same result. The error give's the full path to the button action. "De macro PP50Begroting.xlsm!TOC.btnAction kan niet worden gevonden."

Comment: Would you try as edited: `TOC_WS.CodeName` instead of `TOC_WS.Name`.

Comment: Huh funny, I did try this before and didn't work, but now it does. Thank you very much.